# Endless loop using ng-include

Tags: angularjs

I have the following "master-template":

```
<html ng-app="myApp"><head/>
<body ng-controller="HomeController">
<div class="container" id="mainContent" ng-include="'dashboard/'+menu()+'.html?v='+getRandom()"></div>
</body>
```

Inside the Home-Controller I include content according to the "menu"-parameter:

```
myApp.controller('HomeController',function($scope,$location) {

    $scope.menu=function() {
        var submenu=$location.search().menu;
        if (submenu===undefined) {
            submenu="home"
        }
        return submenu;
    },
    $scope.getRandom=function() {
        return Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1);
    },
    $scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function(event) {
        $(".bsSwitch").bootstrapSwitch();
    });
});
```

(the random-part is only used to stop caching in my dev-environment)

the included template looks like this:

```
<div class="easyBox" ng-controller="CompanyController" ng-init="init()">
<span>nothing to see at all</span>
</div>
```

And has the following controller:

```
myApp.controller('CompanyController',function($scope,$http,$location) {
    $scope.init=function() {
        $http.get('company/get/mine').
            success(function(data,status,headers,config) {
                aboutMe=data;
                console.log("nice");
            }).
            error(function(data,status,headers,config){
                console.log("there was an error");
               // redirectToLogin();

            });
    },
    $scope.aboutMe
});
```

now the problem is that the init()-function from the companyController is called in an endless loop. What might cause this issue and how can it be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one, you should never use a watched expression that changes its value on every digest cycle. `"... + getRandom()"` will never stabilize - and will cause an "infinite loop", which Angular stops after 10 digest iterations.

If you need to avoid caching with a randomized URL, then calculate the URL once when the controller function runs and assign it to a scope variable:

```
$scope.menuUrl = "dashboard/" + menu() + ".html?v=" + getRandom();
```

(also, saves you from having to declare `menu` and `getRandom` on the scope - just keep it as a private function within the controller)

and use that with `ng-include`:

```
<div ng-include="menuUrl"></div>
```

Another thing, although not related to your issue, is the use of `ng-init` - it is not at all needed. The controller function will run once (hence, it is the init function) when the `ng-controller` directive is used:

```
myApp.controller('CompanyController', function($scope, $http, $location) {
    $http.get('company/get/mine')
        .success(function(data,status,headers,config) {
            $scope.aboutMe = data; // this was also a bug 
                                   // assigning data to a global var aboutMe
            console.log("nice");
        })
        .error(function(data,status,headers,config){
            console.log("there was an error");
            // redirectToLogin();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question (following your suggestions). Still endless loop (and much more than 10 times (infinite)) Seems to be the $get() that causes all the trouble

Comment: Well, you shouldn't edit the original content of the question itself - that renders the answer meaningless (with respect to the question) to future visitors. Keep the original question intact, and, if needed, add clarification at the bottom.

Comment: @OleAlbers, and it works fine for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/G3T0PJWb7lMPt44xSRBD?p=preview

Comment: So does for me now. The "random-remove" must not have been updated when I tested. Sorry. You were right.